# passing more data from android view

Tags: java, android

```
private Button.OnClickListener goFirstPage = new Button.OnClickListener() {
```

public void onClick(View v) 
  {
   try 
      {

Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), quizMath.class);
       startActivityForResult(i, 0);

} catch (Exception e) 
   {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // TODO: handle exception
   }

}
 };
hi, this is my code, but the problem is that i want to call a function from class quizmath.So is it possible or not?. can we pass integer or string from startActivityForResult?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. You'll find documentation for Intent here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Before you start the activity you can use the putExtra function on your intent.

```
i.putExtra( "yourapp.function_to_call", "subtract" );
```

This is going to be passed to your activity and you can get out the information with the Intent.getStringExtra function. In your activity you can then do something like this.

```
Intent i = this.getIntent();
String fname = i.getStringExtra( "yourapp.function_to_call" );
if( fname.equals("add") )
    // ...
```

Comment: public void onClick(View v) 
   {
    try 
       {
     
     
     login_profile.makeNewProfile();
     Intent ii = new Intent(v.getContext(), login_profile.class);
     startActivityForResult(ii,0);
     ii.putExtra(com.example.android.login_profile.makeNewProfile(), "bibek");
    
     
   
    }
i did like this but the problem is how can i get the value "bibek" from function makeNewProfile?

Comment: Or can i pass button id from view? i have 4 buttons and each button has same function but i want to know which button is calling a function?

Comment: 1. You have to call putExtra before startActivity. 2. Look at the documentation for Intent. The first parameter has to be a String. Does makeNewProfile() return a String? 3. Have a look at the View documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). You could fore exaple use getId() to identify the calling view.